# после onTouchEvent необходимо отрисовать onDraw на Canvas, а onTouchEvent вызывается чаще, чем успевает отработать onDraw

Tags: java, android

После `onTouchEvent` необходимо отрисовать `onDraw` на `Canvas`, а `onTouchEvent` вызывается чаще, чем успевает отработать `onDraw`. Какое решение лучше? Есть ли еще решения?

1. Сделать флаг `boolean onDrawWorking`(который в начале метода принимает значение 'true', а в конце `false`), и вызывать `onDraw` из `onTouchEvent`, только если флаг `false`

или

2. Добавить переменную `long timeWhenOnDrawFinished`, которая в начале метода `onDraw = null`, а в конце принимает значение времени, когда метод окончил работу. Тогда я смогу контролировать время, и запускать его с определенной задержкой.
3. ? Есть еще варианты?

Каковы + и - первых двух решений? Шде можно почитать про аналогичные решения?